# R: How to make a for loop that performs a formula over a few columns (variables) in a new variable

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, formula

Is it possible to make a for loop in a data frame that produces  an outcome value for every row stored in a new variable/column (i.e., 3 columns (variables) X, Y, and Z. that produces value A for every row depending on values of the same row in those variables).

[image]

For example I want to do 0.5X * 1.2Y + 0.75Z   and put the value in a new column and then loop the same formula for all the rows

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To reiterate akrun below: R structures *themselves* generally contain all the information necessary to define and keep track of loop variables and indeces. Plus vectorized libraries--many of which are already coded to allow for parallel operation under the hood--are highly optimized. LET R DO IT'S JOB and generally give up for/repeat/while/etc. loops for data wrangling. (They can still come in handy in specific and particular places--like invoking parallel foreach for things when running massive Monte Carlo models, but often not even then either).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new = 0.5*X*1.2*Y+0.75*Z)
```

Output:

```
  X Y Z  new
1 1 3 5 5.55
2 4 2 2 6.30
3 2 5 1 6.75
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1,4,2),
                 Y = c(3,2,5),
                 Z = c(5,2,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a vectorized option in `R` - no need for loops

```
df$new <- with(df, (0.5 * X) * (1.2 * Y) + (0.75 *Z))
```